# how to read a json file and print the json body based on ID using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with data as below:

```
 {
   "A": "ID",
   "B": "Priority",
   "C": "Match URL",
   "D": "Match Query",
   "E": "Redirect URL",
   "F": "Status Code",
   "G": "Descr.",
   "H": "Type",
   "I": "Mode",
   "J": "Preserve Query",
   "K": "Start Date",
   "L": "End Date",
   "M": "Actions"
 },
 {
   "A": "24141",
   "B": "",
   "C": "/s/l",
   "D": "",
   "E": "http://local.tb.hello.com/markets/abc.hello.com/mobile/smsLanding.html",
   "F": "0",
   "G": "",
   "H": "String",
   "I": "Internal",
   "J": "",
   "K": "",
   "L": "",
   "M": "Toggle Dropdown"
 },
 {
   "A": "26875",
   "B": "",
   "C": "/l",
   "D": "",
   "E": "http://local.tb.hello.com/markets/abc.hello.com/mobile/smsLanding.html",
   "F": "0",
   "G": "",
   "H": "String",
   "I": "Internal",
   "J": "",
   "K": "",
   "L": "",
   "M": "Toggle Dropdown"
 },
```

I am trying to read the file of the above json file and print the entire body based on ID.
eg: if I give my input for ID as 24141, I should get as below in json format:

```
{
   "A": "24141",
   "B": "",
   "C": "/s/l",
   "D": "",
   "E": "http://local.tb.hello.com/markets/abc.hello.com/mobile/smsLanding.html",
   "F": "0",
   "G": "",
   "H": "String",
   "I": "Internal",
   "J": "",
   "K": "",
   "L": "",
   "M": "Toggle Dropdown"
 }
```

Please help on how to get this achieved. I am new to python so tried reading the file and it can be saved in a string variable, but unable to convert it back to json and based on id.

Comment: Which key name has the id value?

Comment: Your json is invalid. Is that the whole file?

Comment: @adamkgray, i have copied a snippet of the whole file.

Comment: Do you have a dictionary or an array or holding the dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach. There is probably a higher performance route.

```
dd = {Define your json file.}
result = None
find_item = '26875'
for d in dd:
    item = d.get('A', None)
    if find_item == item:
        result = d
        break
print(result)
```